# Recreate View in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, view, toolbar

When open fragment-2 when calling onBackPressed() and opening fragment-1 recreate view, and data is lost(  RecyclerView scrollstate - 0 and Toolbar state becomes as at start) I want recreate it. how was it before the call

Open fragment-2

```
 supportFragmentManager.commit {
            setReorderingAllowed(true)
            setCustomAnimations(
                R.anim.slide_in,
                R.anim.fade_out,
                R.anim.fade_in,
                R.anim.slide_out
            )

            replace<MovieFragment>(
                R.id.fragment_container_view,
                args = MovieFragment.newInstanceBundle(id = id, isFavorite = isFavorite)
            )
            addToBackStack(null)
        }
```

Comment: Are you using the APIs for [restoring your scroll position](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334)? Where are you saving your `Toolbar`'s state? Please include your fragment-1 code.

Comment: I trying save toolbar state and scrool state in local variable, when calling onBackPressed() and stariing metod - onCreateView

Comment: Please include your code.